# Wordpress is not loading Javascript saved as post meta for page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, html-sanitizing

I want to reduce my site load, and want to store `JavaScript` for each page. But all I have tried to load Javascript stored as metadata, go in vain.

Everytime I try to load `JavaScript` it shows `<script> </script>` and blank in between, I want to load `JavaScript` in betweeen `<script> </script>` tag.

Any working method will be appreciated.

```
function myguten_content_filter($content){
    $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'Java-prism-js', true);
    if ( $value ) {
        return sprintf("%s <script> % </script>", $content, esc_html($value) );
    } else {
        return $content;
    }
    }

add_filter( 'the_content', 'myguten_content_filter' );
```

The above code taken from Wordpress [site](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-4-use-data)

**Edit** I forgotten %s, but it still does not render the coveted `Javascript` in site

I want **Working and Tested things** not just petty solutions. I think the database does some kind of sanitization to put `JavaScript` and which might the reason.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the 's' after the % inside the  tag

it should be like

```
"%s <script> %s </script>"
```

Comment: I forgotten %s, but it still does not render the coveted `Javascript` in site

Comment: can you print or var_dump $value, and see what in it

Comment: tried - `echo`, `print` nothing works till now, if possible give something tested and working solution

Comment: yeah, but trying to customise this as your case might be special. can you check if 'Java-prism-js' is the proper key name?

Comment: I think I mistaken to understand custom field, after inserting - the `JavaScript` again it loads - but problem persists 

`JavaScript` does not do its intended work - ` <script type='text/javascript'>`Java-prism-js`</script>'`</div><script>`Java-prism-js</script></div> - the script loads twice. But as obvious <script type="text/javascript"> does the work but gives php error in theme

Comment: Thank you for your effort, I have figured out something more - to achieve **Wordpress** functionalities